# Complex Number Matrix multiplication Eigen vs Matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, eigen

Can someone explain to me why the results are different.

Code in C++:

```
MatrixXcd testTest;
testTest.resize(3,3);
testTest.real()(0,0) = 1;
testTest.real()(0,1) = 2;
testTest.real()(0,2) = 3;
testTest.real()(1,0) = 1;
testTest.real()(1,1) = 2;
testTest.real()(1,2) = 3;
testTest.real()(2,0) = 1;
testTest.real()(2,1) = 2;
testTest.real()(2,2) = 3;

testTest.imag()(0,0) = 1;
testTest.imag()(0,1) = 2;
testTest.imag()(0,2) = 3;
testTest.imag()(1,0) = 1;
testTest.imag()(1,1) = 2;
testTest.imag()(1,2) = 3;
testTest.imag()(2,0) = 1;
testTest.imag()(2,1) = 2;
testTest.imag()(2,2) = 3;

cout<< endl << testTest << endl;
cout<< endl << testTest.transpose() << endl;
cout<< endl << testTest*testTest.transpose() << endl;
cout<< endl << testTest << endl;
```

Results from C++:

```
(1,1) (2,2) (3,3)
(1,1) (2,2) (3,3)
(1,1) (2,2) (3,3)

(1,1) (1,1) (1,1)
(2,2) (2,2) (2,2)
(3,3) (3,3) (3,3)

(0,28) (0,28) (0,28)
(0,28) (0,28) (0,28)
(0,28) (0,28) (0,28)

(1,1) (2,2) (3,3)
(1,1) (2,2) (3,3)
(1,1) (2,2) (3,3)
```

And the same thing written in Matlab:

```
testTest = [ complex(1,1) complex(2,2) complex(3,3); 
             complex(1,1) complex(2,2) complex(3,3); 
             complex(1,1) complex(2,2) complex(3,3)];

testTest
testTest'
testTest*testTest'
testTest
```

Matlab results:

```
testTest =

1.0000 + 1.0000i   2.0000 + 2.0000i   3.0000 + 3.0000i
1.0000 + 1.0000i   2.0000 + 2.0000i   3.0000 + 3.0000i
1.0000 + 1.0000i   2.0000 + 2.0000i   3.0000 + 3.0000i


ans =

1.0000 - 1.0000i   1.0000 - 1.0000i   1.0000 - 1.0000i
2.0000 - 2.0000i   2.0000 - 2.0000i   2.0000 - 2.0000i
3.0000 - 3.0000i   3.0000 - 3.0000i   3.0000 - 3.0000i


ans =

28    28    28
28    28    28
28    28    28


testTest =

1.0000 + 1.0000i   2.0000 + 2.0000i   3.0000 + 3.0000i
1.0000 + 1.0000i   2.0000 + 2.0000i   3.0000 + 3.0000i
1.0000 + 1.0000i   2.0000 + 2.0000i   3.0000 + 3.0000i
```

Multiplication of testTest * testTest' in C returns returns complex numbers with real part 0 and imag part 28. Matlab returns just dobule with value 28.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`'` in Matlab does the transpose and takes the complex conjugate (http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html). If you want to just do the transpose use `.'` (with a dot infront).

Thus, if you change your MATLAB test to

```
testTest*testTest.'
```

the results should be the same.

If you want the complex transpose in eigen then you can go `matrix.adjoint()` (or `matrix.conjugate().transpose()`)

Comment: Thank you for fast and correct answer. I am more focused to implement it in C, so apart from .transpose() I need to call also .conjugate() on my MatrixXcd?

(will accept your answer but I can't within 6 minutes)

Comment: I've added a line in the answer to say how to get the Eigen version to match. You're right - you can add `.conjugate()`, but there if you use `.adjoint()` it does both in one go.

Comment: Thanks, it's so small problem and I lost so much time for it because I didn't notice .translate() doesn't equal ' in Matlab so I was thinking that problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @F1sher 98% of the Matlab users don't know that. First time they realize it, is when they run into a problem like you ;)